# Missing helpers to create vector of structs in Java

Tags: java, flatbuffers

Let's assume the following FlatBuffer schema as an example:

```
struct Ipv6 {
    b0: byte;
    b1: byte;
    b2: byte;
    b3: byte;
    b4: byte;
    b5: byte;
    b6: byte;
    b7: byte;
    b8: byte;
    b9: byte;
    b10: byte;
    b11: byte;
    b12: byte;
    b13: byte;
    b14: byte;
    b15: byte;
}

table Ipv6List {
    entries: [Ipv6];
}

root_type Ipv6List;
```

The problem I have is with the creation of a vector that contains *Ipv6* structs. The Java class `Ipv6List` generated by Flatbuffer *1.11.0* does not include the usual *create* helper. Reading the documentation it seems to be a design choice to improve performance by preventing the creation of a temp object.

Looking at other methods, there is a `Ipv6List#startEntriesVector` static function but no associated `addX` and `endX` function. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
FlatBufferBuilder builder = new FlatBufferBuilder();

final byte[] inetAddressBytes =
        Inet6Address.getByName("2a01:e35:2e7a:490:6193:c54c:f740:f907").getAddress();

int ipv6Offset = Ipv6.createIpv6(builder,
        inetAddressBytes[0], inetAddressBytes[1], inetAddressBytes[2], inetAddressBytes[3],
        inetAddressBytes[4], inetAddressBytes[5], inetAddressBytes[6], inetAddressBytes[7],
        inetAddressBytes[8], inetAddressBytes[9], inetAddressBytes[10], inetAddressBytes[11],
        inetAddressBytes[12], inetAddressBytes[13], inetAddressBytes[14], inetAddressBytes[15]
);

Ipv6List.startEntriesVector(builder, 1);

// how to add the IP to the vector ?
// how to end the association and get the vector offset ?
// int ipsVectorOffset = ?;

int ipListOffset = Ipv6List.createIpv6List(builder, ipsVectorOffset);
builder.finish(ipListOffset);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = builder.dataBuffer();
```

Any idea how to create a vector of Ipv6 struct and to associate it with the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structs always need to be created inline, so the order of operations should be:

```
Ipv6List.startEntriesVector(builder, 1);
Ipv6.createIpv6(builder,..);
o = builder.endVector();
Ipv6List.createIpv6List(builder, o);
```

Comment: Thanks for point this issue but my root problem is that there is even no `Ipv6List.end...` method :( It looks like a Struct needs to be part of a Table to have the `endX` method generated. Using it directly as a Vector does not generate the method. Is it a requirement or a bug? in the former, it would be really helpful to have an error that is raised at compile time.

Comment: As shown in https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html you can just call `builder.endVector()`, let me fix that in the answer.